# CodeIgniter with less URL segments

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

As you might know, the URL for codeigniter is build [like this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html). In my case, I have:

```
http://example.com/subfolder/class/function/ID
```

Is there a way with codeigniter (or htaccess) to create this url in a much shorter url like this:

```
http://example.com/ID
```

Kind regards, Senne

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `application/configs/routes.php` file, you should be able to add something like this:

```
$routes['(:num)'] = 'your_controller/your_function/$1'
```

You can read more about custom routing here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using [Url Routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html) in CodeIgniter.

```
$route[':any'] = "subfolder/class/function/$1";
```